# How to know if a remote machine has a display attached to it?

Tags: ssh, display

I have remote access to a Linux machine. How would I know if the machine is headless or it has a display attached to it?
If I `ssh` into it and run `echo $DISPLAY` I don't get any output. Does it mean there is no display?

Comment: The `ssh and echo $DISPLAY` test tells you nothing useful about any screen attached to the machine. You need to explain what you mean by a display attached. For example if there was a screen attached and someone logged in on it but then the screen was powered off, would you consider there to be a display attached? What happens if you unplug the screen without logging off, so you can plug it in later?

Comment: It would be easy to check for a running graphical server and/or login screen - just look for X and/or wayland in the list of running programs. Or course there could still be a screen attached but only in text mode. Which of the two do you wish to detect?

Comment: well I would like to use VNC, so I guess it has to be a monitor turned on

Comment: For using VNC you need to make sure VNC server runs on that server. To see if monitor is connected you can run `xrandr -display <display number>` (like `xrandr -display :0`). You can even download EDID information from monitor with `get-edid`. For that command, monitor has to be connected and switched on in order to get information from it. But I think you are more interested in information that Xorg or Wayland is running and VNC server, too.

Comment: @Vaaal88 VNC does not need a physical display. https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/vncserver.1.html